# Linux: why doesnt sed -e '1,244d' remove

Tags: linux, bash

why doesn't sed -e '1,244d'  remove the first 244 lines of a text file. I've used this code many time albeit with much smaller line counts
here is a copy of the code:

```
    sed -e '1,244d' /home/user/Documents/working_files/storage/file.txt <> /home/user/Documents/working_files/storage/file.txt
```

I test the script in bash and nothing happens, I run it under sudo and it displays the script modified per the script, but it does not append/overwrite to the file, I used the "<>" option to try to get the script to clear the un-needed and then not have to append it into a new file.
any help would be greatly appeciated. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried `sed -i`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax,

```
sed -e '1,244d' /home/user/Documents/working_files/storage/file.txt <> /home/user/Documents/working_files/storage/file.txt
                                                                   ^^^^
```

the <> doesn't mean what you think it means. (See below)

If you want to redirect the output of sed to a file you would use `>` like so:

```
sed -e '1,244d' file.txt > output.txt
```

NOTICE that I specified a DIFFERENT filename for the output.  You should NEVER use input file as the output of a redirect...

A better way to do this would be:

```
sed -e '1,244d' -i file.txt
```

This will edit the file *in place*.

### More on <>

<> operator doesn't mean what you THINK it means.  If you do something like:

```
 sed -e '1,244d' file.txt <> file.txt
```

is STILL meaningless.  In this case there is NO redirection of the output to file.txt because actually fd0 is reopened so any writes to fd 0 go to file.txt

The following is example is quoted from tldp  to further explain what to use <> for:

```
  #  Open file "filename" for reading and writing,
  #+ and assign file descriptor "j" to it.
  #  If "filename" does not exist, create it.
  #  If file descriptor "j" is not specified, default to fd 0, stdin.
  #
  #  An application of this is writing at a specified place in a file. 
  echo 1234567890 > File    # Write string to "File".
  exec 3<> File             # Open "File" and assign fd 3 to it.
  read -n 4 <&3             # Read only 4 characters.
  echo -n . >&3             # Write a decimal point there.
  exec 3>&-                 # Close fd 3.
  cat File                  # ==> 1234.67890
  #  Random access, by golly.
```

Comment: `<>` is the [*diamond operator*](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/).

Comment: `<>` is Bash specific, afaik.  You cannot expect to find that everywhere.  To be fair, the OP does say Bash, though.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: the question is tagged bash, so this is bash programming, not shell in general.

Comment: As I state in my comment @CommuSoft

Comment: ah yes... I've only used it for explicit file descriptors forgot that it tied to stdin for no fd

Comment: <> is actually posix not just bash specific.

Comment: btw, `<>` has somewhat slightly different meaning in perl5.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: indeed: it assigns the read and file handle to the same file descriptor. But it is probably better not to do inline editing for file in an OS content anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

You can use

```
command < file | sponge file
```

So in this case:

```
sed -e '1,244d' file | sponge file
```

`sponge` (`moreutils`) is a command that *soaks* the `stdin` into memory and when finished writes to `file`. So this enables one to do "inline" modifications.

## Fair warning about inline modifications

First of all a warning: **don't do inline replacements**. If the server crashes in the middle of the process, the file can get corrupted, and it that case you can have lost both the original and the new file. `sponge` cannot undo this effect: say you use `sed -e '1,244d' file | sponge file` it is possible that `sed` finishes its job, and now `sponge` starts writing to `file`. But in the middle of the process the machine crashes and thus the content of the original file is gone and you only can recover the part that `sponge` already wrote.

You better use:

```
command < file > tempfile
mv -f tempfile file
```

as @CharlesDuffy suggests.

Which is a more atomic version of:

```
command < file > tempfile
cp tempfile file
rm tempfile
```

So that in case the machine crashes (for instance there is a power failure) at some part, you always have at least or the original file; or the resulting file.

## The problem with the diamond operator `<>`

The [diamond operator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) has a specification that is hard to understand:

> ```
> [j]<>filename
>       #  Open file "filename" for reading and writing,
>       #+ and assign file descriptor "j" to it.
>       #  If "filename" does not exist, create it.
>       #  If file descriptor "j" is not specified, default to fd 0, stdin.
> ```

It thus means that **both reading and writing are assigned to `stdin`**, not reading to `stdin` and writing from `stdout`. So the diamond operator **cannot be used for automatic inline replacement**, unless the program uses the file descriptors bidirectionally.

## Bidirectional processing

As said, there exist utility programs like `sponge` that allow to store the result temporary in memory and only saves to a file when `stdin` closes.

## `sed` specific inline edits

`sed` also has an `--in-place` flag:

> ```
> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>        edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
> ```

So by running:

```
sed -e '1,244d' -i file
```

You can do inline modifications.

Comment: Thanks I just tried it and it works thanks for you help to all of you, my thanks

Comment: One serious fault in this advice: `cp` is not atomic. Better to suggest `mv`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `cp` doesn't have to be atomic. Since the `tmpfile` still exists, one can still recover the data. Anywhere in the process, at least one of the files remains "untouched" (in the sense there is no content written to it).

Comment: If you're willing to rely on manual recovery, sure -- but why would you do that, when you can use `mv` and ensure that you'll never have half a new file in the destination location?

Comment: There are also race conditions around content -- something can see the new file while it's still partial in the `cp` case, whereas the new file is only visible at all when complete when using `mv`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I've added your suggestion to the answer. Point taken about automatic recovery.

Comment: Good deal. I might add a note about use of `mktemp` if I were writing this myself, given its importance in avoiding security issues (see: attacker creating a symlink to a file they can't write to directly themselves using a hardcoded tempfile name in a jointly-writable directory; script with different/more privileges tries to write to temporary file with that name, truncates/overwrites symlink target). Also, the gotchas (around preserving ownership/permissions) are worth noting (`chown --reference`, `chmod --reference` and friends are handy tools if one is targeting a modern GNU platform).

Comment: in sed, it's better idea to have it write file directly and back the file up btw. you've shown the syntax, it should be `sed -i.bak -e 'modification' file`, then you can do cp and rm.